# Redemption & MAPI - MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND LogonExchangeMailbox

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I'm having a bit of trouble getting this working.

I have a 32 bit C# application deployed on a 2012 server. I have a reference to Interop.Redemption which is a local copy / not embedded and have installed the standalone Exchange Server MAPI CDO 1.2.1 on that server. The exchange version it would try to connect to is 2010.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in IMsgServiceAdmin::CreateMsgService: MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND
```

at the offending line:

```
RDOSession oRDOSession = new RDOSession();
oRDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox("username", "mailserver.com");
```

From the reading I've done on this error a lot seems to come up around mapisvc.inf - I do not have these files in either system32 or Program Files. I do have them in 3 locations:

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-fax-mapi_--SNIPPED--
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-fax-mapi_--SNIPPED--
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
content of C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mapisvc.INF file:

```
**[Default Services]
MSEMS=Microsoft Exchange Server

[Services]
MSEMS=Microsoft Exchange Server
MSPST MS=Outlook 97-2002 Personal Folders File (.pst)

[MSEMS]
PR_DISPLAY_NAME=Microsoft Exchange Server
Sections=MSEMS_MSMail_Section
PR_SERVICE_DLL_NAME=emsui.dll
PR_SERVICE_ENTRY_NAME=EMSCfg
PR_RESOURCE_FLAGS=SERVICE_SINGLE_COPY
WIZARD_ENTRY_NAME=EMSWizardEntry
Providers=ems_dsa, ems_mdb_public, ems_mdb_private
PR_SERVICE_SUPPORT_FILES=emsui.dll, emsabp.dll, emsmdb.dll**
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the MAPI system?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have done yes. using this install: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045

Comment: Does the mapisvc.inf file have the entry for MSEMS service?

Comment: which of the files is the correct one? there's 3, they all look the same:

Comment: updated the original post with the INF file content

Comment: ahh ... the ones under C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-fax-mapi_--SNIPPED--
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-fax-mapi_--SNIPPED-- don't have the MSEMS section ...

Comment: Can you rename them?

Comment: which ones? which file is the correct one/where should it be placed?

Comment: The one that has MSEMS is the right one. Try to rename the bad ones so they cannot be picked up by MAPI.

Comment: Ah that's done it! if you can put that as an answer I'll accept it. However for clarification, I'm a little uncomfortable leaving those files names as '.old' - do you know why those files would even exist there? I've certainly not installed them.

Comment: I don't know why these files are created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete or rename the mapisvc.inf files that do not contain the MSEMS service.

Comment: Perfect - as per comments I'm not sure why or how these files are created but it seems safe enough to delete / rename them.